# What type do I specify for react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, typeof

Pretty straight forward question. 
I come from a Qt/C++ background, and so I regard it as good practice to be explicit, thus

```js
protected sanityCheck() : void { ... } // Smart and beautiful
protected sanityCheck() { ... }        // Stupid and always wrong
```

Well, how do I be explicit with this:

```js
protected toFoobar() : ?????
{
        return ( <h1> foobar </h1> );
}
```

When I checked the documentation, it doesnt say anything. When I checked the typeof, it just said object.

Would this be the answer, or can I even be more specific?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type would be `JSX.Element`. that's what the JSX syntax always evaluates to. If you use React, `JSX.Element` is just a type reference to `React.Element<any, any>`.

Comment: So what exactly should my line of code be? The only thing that works is `protected toFoobar() : JSX.Element[]` which seems strange.

Comment: @akiva no, `JSX.Element`.

Comment: `Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key  TS2739` << Doesn't work for me. My class is a generic if that matters.

Comment: No I realized you were right; The reason why the array worked, is that my return statement was a map expression.

Answer (score -1):

React does provide type for functional components in React 
You can do as so

```
const toFoobar: React.FunctionComponent<IFoobar> = ({propsType}) => ();
```

this is new in React before it was React.SFC

Hope it helps

Comment: what is IFoobar supposed to be?

Comment: its interface like interface IFoobar{
    name: string // type of props 
}

Comment: doesn't work. `Type 'Element[]' provides no match for the signature '(props: PropsWithChildren<Props_QPoll<T>>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | null'.  TS2322` Might be because my props interface is a generic.